# Lost, confused and out of options in Unbreakable Kimmy Schmidt

Tags: reference, unbreakable-kimmy-schmidt

In *Unbreakable Kimmy Schmidt* S4 E9, "Sliding Van Doors," at about 43:30, alternate timeline Kimmy and Titus meet and have this exchange:

> Kimmy: I'm so lost.
> Titus: Are you also confused and out of options?

This sounds familiar to me, and is doubtless a reference to something, but neither a web search nor a search of knowyourmeme.com for "lost confused out of options" provides any hints.

To what does this refer?

Comment: I can’t find any close examples right now, but I feel like there’s been some billboard or something that has a message similar to “Lost? Confused? Out of options? Jesus is the answer!” Or something like that.

Comment: Or it could be signs for a suicide hotline.